# What are the steps and elements/requirements to develop a web service?

Tags: web-services, web

I've read a lot of threads regarding with Web Service app, but i want to know your idea about my case here.

We will be developing a Web Service that can update our local server's db and at the same time to a remote server's db via (internet)

PL: C#, VS2012
DB(Local): SQL2008r2
DB(remote): N/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to explain it using architecture and not the programming language. Your case is the norm in the current SOA and Microservices architectures. A service is governing one function and it has REST APIs for clients to do CRUD and the REST APIs store it in a data store behind the service. 
All services generate events for the CRUD and send it to message bus so that any other client/service interested in its state change can listen to the messages and act upon it.

So essentially you can do the "Remote server's DB via internet" part asynchronously.

Hope that helps.